Weekly Topic Challenge: Let's ask about Scalability‽
Scalability has been a hot topic in the Bitcoin community for some months, and we've got it covered somewhat already with 60 questions tagged on the site.
Please use scalability to tag your questions, and consider asking any questions about Bitcoin's capacity to grow, current scalability proposals, and scaling challenges.
Please also check out the previous work, add more answers where they are missing, improve content where it should be, and vote on what's there!
This weekly topic challenge runs until 2016-12-08. Happy posting!

There was one questions asked about scalability which was unfortunately put on hold for being unclear.
